# How can I scroll inside an iframe, if the iframe has no scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anybody now a solution for the following or at least know, where to find the documentation of this restriction?

I have a html page (the parent) including an iframe (child) without an libraries, just pure javascript and html. It does not matter if both are on the same domain or not. When I add an iframe with a height of 400px to my parent page and the child page inside the iframe is higher, it shows a scrollbar for the iframe. Inside my child page I add a button, which scrolls to position top: 100, left: 0 onclick, which means, that the iframe content is scrolled to its stop. This is working.

When I add an iframe with the height of 2200px, which is higher that the child iframe content and thus there is no scrollbar, this click event is not scrolling anymore.

The practical part:

What I want to solve is, that I have a parent page with a seamless integrated iframe. the iframe has much content, including forms. On smaller displays you have to scroll a bit, fill out the forms, scroll further and confirm a terms button. This validates the form fields and if a form is invalid, I want the iframe content to scroll to its position of the first invalid input fiel, if it is not in the current viewport

I tested it with current Firefox 109.

This is not a same domain issue, the actual logic works when not inside the iframe.

example parent code:

```
<h2>IFrame Resizing Testpage parent</h2>
<iframe src="scrolling-page.html" width="100%" height="400px" style="border:2px solid green;"></iframe>
<hr>
<iframe src="scrolling-page.html" width="100%" height="2200px" id="iframe-scrolling" style="border:2px solid red;"></iframe>
```

Example code of the child page:

```
<h2>IFrame Resizing Testpage</h2>
<div style="height: 2000px"></div>

<h2>IFrame Resizing Testpage End</h2>

<button id="scroll" type="button">scroll</button>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

        document.getElementById('scroll').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            console.log('test');
            window.scrollTo(100, 0);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So you want it to also scroll the parent page to bring it into view? Then you will need to communicate with the iFrame with `postMessage` and then scroll the parent page when the child sends an event...

Comment: Is "scrolling the parent page" the same as scrolling to an element of the child page into view?

Comment: Nope, iframes do not share that info. You would have to calculate how much to scroll the parent based on an offset passed to it. So '400 from the iframe top', which on the parent page is 'offset top iframe + 400 from iframe top' or something, and then scroll there...

Comment: Ok, I thing I got it. The limitation, that the child website inside the iframe is not allowed to access the parent website is clear, so the child needs to communicate with the parent by the postMessage feature. When there is no scrollbar for the iframe itself, the scrolling is in the scope of the parent, thus can not be accessed.